# Extract two substrings from String surronded by special string (Java)

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String like this..

```
I am a !!!guy!!! but I like !!!cats!!! better than dogs.
```

I need the strings within the exclamation Strings (!!!), a collection of Strings or array will do.

I can probably do this a dirty way with String's substring and indexOf, but if you can suggest a better way with regular expressions or just cleaner code that would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: learn more about java regex and use split method in string class

Comment: Since you seem to know regular expressions, why not try something with regex before you ask?

Comment: You may want to also look at match, find and group in java.util.regex.Matcher

Comment: I never said I knew regex, I know the concept of it but not all the rules of how to look for particular strings. Why did you down vote my question when I am just trying to learn?

Comment: What do you expect from this string: `I am a !!!g!u!y!!! but!!!.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
!!!(.*?)!!!
```

And then grab the capturing group content

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF3hC8/1)**

[image]

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [10-13] `guy`
MATCH 2
1.  [31-35] `cats`
```

You can use something like this java code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches
{
    public static void main( String args[] ){

      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "I am a !!!guy!!! but I like !!!cats!!! better than dogs.";
      String pattern = "!!!(.*?)!!!";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      while (m.find( )) {
         //--> If you want a array do the logic you want with m.group(1)
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fede, nice to see some nice guys here.